# Validating a form using Styled-components doesn't behave like CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, styled-components

I've found a very simple and efficient tutorial to handle **form validation and errors handling** with just React and CSS : https://medium.com/@everdimension/how-to-handle-forms-with-just-react-ac066c48bd4f

This solution is working like a charm. But I wanted to reproduce the exact **same behavior using the css-in-js library styled-components.**

The solution to handle the errors in the tutorial was to switch the class of the FORM and target the pseudo class :invalid of the input child to apply a red border around the inputs. And it works perfectly using just CSS classes. I tried to use the same system with styled-components, but it went wrong.

I did 2 fiddle to show you the difference in behavior

- **Only CSS** => [fiddle with css](https://jsfiddle.net/Battouste/fjyp862u/)

js

```
    const Form = () => {
      const [error, setError] = React.useState(false)

      const handleSubmit = React.useCallback((event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
          setError(true);
          return;
        }

        setError(false)
        console.log('Do something')
      }, [error, setError])

      return(
        <div>
          <h1>With pure CSS</h1>
          <h2>Good behavior : </h2>
          <h2>1 . Press submit => the input goes red </h2>
          <h2>2 . Fill one of the input => cleans the red border individually</h2>
          <form 
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          noValidate
          className={error ? "displayErrors" : ""}
        >
          <input className='input' required></input>
          <input className='input' required></input>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit!"></input>
        </form>
        </div>
      )
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

css

```
    .displayErrors input:invalid {
      border-color: red;
    }
```

- Using **styled-components** => [Fiddle with styled-components](https://jsfiddle.net/Battouste/Lac6ezxk/)

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
`

const StyledForm = styled.form`
  &:invalid ${StyledInput} {
    border-color: ${props => {
      console.log(props.error)
      return props.error ? "red" : "none"
    }};
  }
`;


const Form = () => {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false)

  const handleSubmit = React.useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
      setError(true);
      return;
    }

    setError(false)
    console.log('Do something')
  }, [error, setError])

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>With Styled components</h1>
      <h2>To reproduce the issue : </h2>
      <h2>1 - press submit, the inputs goes red </h2>
      <h2>2 - fill one input => ISSUE => the input (which is no more invalid) stays red  </h2>
  <StyledForm 
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      noValidate
      error={error}
    >
      <StyledInput className='input' required></StyledInput>
      <StyledInput className='input' required></StyledInput>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit!"></input>
    </StyledForm>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

The expected behavior on the first fiddle (CSS):

1. Press submit, the inputs goes red
2. Fill one input => The red border is cleaned **individually** (which means one input status doesn't depend on the other)

To reproduce the issue on the second fiddle (Styled-components):

1. Press submit, the inputs goes red
2. Fill one input => ISSUE => the input (which is no more invalid) **stays red** as long as the second input is still invalid (which means the two input are related).

My problem is that in the styled-components version the red borders of the inputs are cleaned when **the both of the inputs are valid**. But I want the inputs to act individually like in the CSS version.

I know there is 100 of solutions to solve the problem but I really liked the easy and clean solution of the tutorial. I expected to have the same behavior on both sides, could be a bug? Is there something i'm missing? Please help <3

Comment: I think you should reverse the invalid in your styles component: I tried  this in your jsfiddle and it seems to work as expecte ; `& ${StyledInput}:invalid {
    border-color: ${props => {
     console.log(props.error)
  ....`

Comment: Woaw. It works actually ! Thanks a lot @Jerome ! Can you explain what is happening here ?

Comment: I just found that ```& :invalid${StyledInput} { border-color: ...``` works just fine too...

Comment: Well the invalid test is done at input level not form level (this is the required props in your styledinput components). It makes more sense then to style input:invalid than form:invalid input...